Opensource SonarQube and heterogeneous source code (C++, C#, Java, Python)
I work on relatively large project which uses multiple programming languages  - C++ 23, C# (.NET 8), Java 17, Python 3.
At the moment, SonarQube (opensource version) has separate project for each language.
I spent quite some time trying to set up a combined project so metrics can be obtained for entire codebase at once. C++ and Python worked just fine, but C# and Java didn't work - sonar-scanner-cli throws various errors telling to run dedicated version for specific platform.
Tried to make SonarQube for .Net pick C++ coverage and test results - no errors yet nothing C++-related appeared in the SonarQube UI.
Any hint on how to make aforementioned task implemented would be greatly appreciated.
A proof of impossibility of said solution would be of great help, too.
